# Add more horizontal space between matrices

Tags: matrices

I have two questions:

1. How can I add more horizontal spacing between the matrices?
2. Furthermore, is there a way to add some text above the matrices?

I added a picture with the desired ouput.

Here's a MWE to obtain the matrices on the left:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\begin{document}

\[
\begin{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
{
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 4 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 0 \\
   0 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 2 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 4 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   };  
   \draw[color=red] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}\\
%\end{bmatrix}\\
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
{
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 9 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 0 \\
   0 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 2 & 0 \\
   0 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   };  
   \draw[color=green] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
{
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   0 & 3 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 9 & 0 \\
   0 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 0 \\
   0 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
   0 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 5 & 0 \\
   0 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 3 & 0 \\
   0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
   };  
   \draw[color=blue] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
%
\begin{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
{
0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 1 \\
   };  
   \draw[color=red] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
{
0 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
   };  
   \draw[color=green] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
{
1 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
1 & 1 & 0 \\
   };  
   \draw[color=blue] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
=
\begin{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
 \begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
{
1 & 1 & 1 \\
0 & 1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 \\
   };  
   \draw[color=yellow] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-1.north east) -- (m-1-1.south east) -- (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
\end{matrix}
\label{eq:convex}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image: matrix]

Comment: While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

This is especially important for `tikz` as there are numerous libraries.

Comment: You're right! I edited the code.

Comment: you have in your example `\begin{matrix}` immediately following `\end{matrix}`, so of course there is no horizontal space.  insert `\qquad` or `\hspace{<dimen>}` to specify as much space as you want.  this is an elementary principle governing spaces in tex math.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put your matrices in an `array` environment, that way you can easily put title on top of your columns. As for the extra space, you can then set the desired length using `arraycolsep`.

**Edit:** as egreg stated in the comments, `\arraycolsep` affects the placement of `pmatrix`, so to set extra space between the matrices, use `\begin{array{@{}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{}}` instead.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,chains,positioning,decorations.pathreplacing,arrows}
\setlength{\arraycolsep}{20pt}

\begin{document}

\[
    \begin{array{@{}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{}}
    Title 1 & Title 2 & & Title 3\\
    \begin{matrix}
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
                    {
                        0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                    0 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
                    0 & 2 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 4 & 0 \\
                    0 & 1 & 8 & 4 & 1 & 7 & 0 \\
                    0 & 6 & 3 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 0 \\
                    0 & 2 & 1 & 7 & 8 & 4 & 0 \\
                    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                };  
                    \draw[color=red] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{bmatrix}\\
        %\end{bmatrix}\\
        \\
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
                {
                    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                0 & 1 & 3 & 1 & 0 & 2 & 0 \\
                0 & 9 & 3 & 4 & 2 & 6 & 0 \\
                0 & 1 & 2 & 8 & 9 & 2 & 0 \\
                0 & 5 & 6 & 4 & 5 & 1 & 0 \\
                0 & 7 & 5 & 3 & 3 & 7 & 0 \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            };  
                \draw[color=green] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{bmatrix}\\ 
        \\
        \begin{bmatrix}
            \begin{tikzpicture}
                \matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
                {
                    0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
                0 & 3 & 1 & 8 & 1 & 9 & 0 \\
                0 & 4 & 5 & 2 & 1 & 8 & 0 \\
                0 & 7 & 6 & 3 & 1 & 1 & 0 \\
                0 & 7 & 4 & 8 & 2 & 5 & 0 \\
                0 & 8 & 4 & 8 & 8 & 3 & 0 \\
                0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
            };  
                \draw[color=blue] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
            \end{tikzpicture}
        \end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
&
\begin{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
        {
            0 & 1 & 0 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 1 \\
    };  
        \draw[color=red] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
        {
            0 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
    };  
        \draw[color=green] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
\\
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
        {
            1 & 0 & 1 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
        1 & 1 & 0 \\
    };  
        \draw[color=blue] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-3.north east) -- (m-3-3.south east) -- (m-3-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}
\end{matrix}
& = &
\begin{matrix}
\begin{bmatrix}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        \matrix [matrix of math nodes] (m)
        {
            1 & 1 & 1 \\
        0 & 1 & 1 \\
        1 & 0 & 0 \\
    };  
        \draw[color=yellow] (m-1-1.north west) -- (m-1-1.north east) -- (m-1-1.south east) -- (m-1-1.south west) -- (m-1-1.north west);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{bmatrix}\\ 
\end{matrix}
\label{eq:convex}
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image: matrices with title and space]

Comment: Does setting `\arraycolsep` affect the spacing for `pmatrix` as well?

Comment: I don't think so, but I'm no expert of the internals of the `amsmath`, sorry.

Comment: @Werner Of course it does

Comment: Instead of setting `\arraycolsep`, wouldn't it be easier to use `\begin{array}{@{}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{\hspace{20pt}}c@{}}`?

Comment: Sorry for the late question. I was wondering how I can add a title which contains two words. Now, when I want to write for example, ''the first'' latex compiles it as ''thefirst''. There is no space?

Comment: @egreg it seems to be working yes, I will update my answer then.
@apples-oranges this is because you're in math mode. You can use `\text{}`to print text with spaces.

Comment: Previous code doesn't compile with overleaf and texmaker with Miktex 2.9. Is there an option to get it runnable?